# What browsers support 'grouped post fields'?

Tags: html, forms, post, cross-browser

Do all browsers support 'grouped post fields'? I'm not sure grouped post fields is the correct term here but I'll explain what I mean. In a form I give input fields an array index prefix such as `foo[1]` and then when I POST the data it is nicely grouped (see below for an example).

My question is, do all browsers support this or will I have issues with Safari on iPhone, Edge, old versions of Firefox? Is there a website I can find out more information about support for this?

Example usage of 'grouped post fields':

```
<input type='text' name='applicant[1][fullname]' placeholder='Full Name'>
<input type='email' name='applicant[1][email]' placeholder='Email'>

<input type='text' name='applicant[2][fullname]' placeholder='Full Name'>
<input type='email' name='applicant[2][email]' placeholder='Email'>

....
```

In PHP my posted data comes through nicely grouped like this:

```
echo print_r($_POST, false);

/*
"applicant": {
    "1": {
        "fullname": "Foo Bar",
        "email": "foo@bar.com"
    },
    "2": {
        "fullname": "Foo Bar",
        "email": "foo@bar.com"
    },
    ...
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the browser is concerned, those are sent as four name-value pairs, with names being what you wrote: `applicant[1][fullname]` etc. It is PHP that assumes those are to be automagically put into one data structure under `$_POST["applicant"]`. Thus, since browsers have nothing to do with this, this will work with every browser, as long as you are using PHP on the backend.